# Parse xml file in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml file in groovy for jenkins and save a specific value to a variable.
XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject plugin="workflow-multibranch@2.21">
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <properties>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.declarative.FolderConfig plugin="docker-workflow@1.23">
      <dockerLabel></dockerLabel>
      <registry plugin="docker-commons@1.16"/>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.declarative.FolderConfig>
  </properties>
  <folderViews class="jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProjectViewHolder" plugin="branch-api@2.5.6">
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
  </folderViews>
  <healthMetrics>
    <com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.health.WorstChildHealthMetric plugin="cloudbees-folder@6.12">
      <nonRecursive>false</nonRecursive>
    </com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.health.WorstChildHealthMetric>
  </healthMetrics>
  <icon class="jenkins.branch.MetadataActionFolderIcon" plugin="branch-api@2.5.6">
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
  </icon>
  <orphanedItemStrategy class="com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.DefaultOrphanedItemStrategy" plugin="cloudbees-folder@6.12">
    <pruneDeadBranches>true</pruneDeadBranches>
    <daysToKeep>10</daysToKeep>
    <numToKeep>10</numToKeep>
  </orphanedItemStrategy>
  <triggers/>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <sources class="jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList" plugin="branch-api@2.5.6">
    <data>
      <jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
        <source class="jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource" plugin="git@4.2.2">
          <id>abcdefg</id>
          <remote>git@github.com:x/y.git</remote>
          <credentialsId>githubcredentials</credentialsId>
          <traits>
            <jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait/>
            <jenkins.scm.impl.trait.WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait plugin="scm-api@2.6.3">
              <includes>branch*</includes>
              <excludes></excludes>
            </jenkins.scm.impl.trait.WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait>
          </traits>
        </source>
        <strategy class="jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy">
          <properties class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
            <a class="jenkins.branch.BranchProperty-array">
              <jenkins.branch.NoTriggerBranchProperty/>
            </a>
          </properties>
        </strategy>
      </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
    </data>
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
  </sources>
  <factory class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory">
    <owner class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject" reference="../.."/>
    <scriptPath>ci/x/y.jenkinsfile</scriptPath>
  </factory>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject>
```

The value I need to write to a variable is "branch*", from "jenkins.scm.impl.trait.WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait".

What I have done so far:

```
def job = "ci/x/y.jenkinsfile"

def config = job.getConfigFile()
println("[INFO] loading xml: " + config)
File file = config.getFile()
def xml=new XmlParser().parse(file)
```

Now, if I add this piece of code "println xml.children()" I do get everything starting from actions.
So I tried to add "println xml.children().sources()" and further more to reach to the value I want, but I keep getting error messages.

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much about XML structure

```
def xmlDetails = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlText)
def data= xmlDetails.
        sources.
        data.
        "jenkins.branch.BranchSource".
        source.traits.
        "jenkins.scm.impl.trait.WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait"."includes".text()

assert data=="branch*"
```

(https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-reading-xml.html )

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with this I'm still getting "No such field found: field groovy.util.Node sources"

Comment: I tried it in Groovy web console and it works with the same xml, but for some reason I don't know why it is failing in jenkins

Comment: This works for me, but when I first tried it, the `$` in `$BranchSourceList` broke it with: `No such property: BranchSourceList for class: ...` Groovy wants to parse that as a variable.

Comment: @ou_ryperd you are saying it worked for you in jenkins?

Comment: No, the parsing part in Eclipse. See the rest of my comment though.

Comment: [UPDATE] It is working now, I had to use this syntax: `def data = xmlDetails['sources']['data']['jenkins.branch.BranchSource']['source']['traits']['jenkins.scm.impl.trait.WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait']['includes'].text()`